# Problema al visualizar label de valores en Chartjs y Datalabels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, plugin

Estoy usando [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/) para graficar unos valores en un gráfico de Barras, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando mostrar estos valores en un label con el plugin [datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/labels.html) , hasta aquí todo bien, sin embargo uno de los valores de la gráfica cuando esta se hace mas grande el valor sale del "Canvas" y no logro verlo correctamente.

Ya he intentado modificar el Height del canvas pero eso no lo soluciona, lo que hace es que me estira el gráfico.

**Lo que he investigado:**

Si el legend es mostrada Options > Legend, entonces me crea un cuadrito arriba de las barras y todo se visualiza asi como quiero, el problema es que ya intente cambiar el color de ese cuadrito por ejemplo a `#fff` para simular que no está y no me acepta la propiedad asi como lo veo en la documentacion de [Legend | ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html)

Si la Legend no se muestra en el gráfico entonces ocurre el problema de que los valores de la gráfica se salen del canvas y no se visualizan.

Quisiera que la leyenda estuviera oculta pero que también mi gráfico se mostrará asi como cuando esta activa.

```
options: {
            legend :{
              display:false,
              labels:{
                color:'#fff'
                }
            }...
```

Código de ejemplo:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
let myChart = null;

// valores por defecto en la grafica
crearGrafica(3000, 8000);

function cargar() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 & this.status == 200) {
            let obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

            //Create the graph
            crearGrafica(4000, 5000);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "livenumbers.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function crearGrafica(valor1, valor2) {
    // Si ya se creó la gráfica
    if (myChart !== null) {
        // Destruir para poder crear nuevamente
        myChart.destroy();
    }
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Valor1', 'Valor2'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '',
                data: [valor1, valor2],
                minBarLength: 80,
                barThickness: 100,
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#322c83',
                    '#ea7123'
                ],
                datalabels: {
                    color: '#000',
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold',
                    },
                    formatter: (value, context) => {
                        return '$ ' + parseInt(value).toLocaleString('en-US');
                    },
                    //Aqui controlo la ubicacion de mis labels encima del grafico
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'top',
                    offset: 0,
                    display: true
                }

            }]
        },
        options: {
            //quisiera que la legenda estuviera oculta pero que tambien mi grafico se mostrara como quiero
            legend :{
              display:false,
              labels:{
                color:'#fff'
                }
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem) {
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    }
                }
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        drawBorder: false,
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        display: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }],

                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        drawBorder: false,
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- for canvas chart -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
          <span style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"> Mi grafica
          </span>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px;margin-top:10%"></canvas>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="container" style="text-align:center">

      </div>
    </div>
```

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es configurar manualmente [`padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html?h=padding) al `top` del gráfico para evitar que los `labels` se salgan del canvas.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
let myChart = null;

// valores por defecto en la grafica
crearGrafica(3000, 8000);

function cargar() {
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 & this.status == 200) {
      let obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

      //Create the graph
      crearGrafica(4000, 5000);
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "livenumbers.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function crearGrafica(valor1, valor2) {
  // Si ya se creó la gráfica
  if (myChart !== null) {
    // Destruir para poder crear nuevamente
    myChart.destroy();
  }
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Valor1', 'Valor2'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '',
        data: [valor1, valor2],
        minBarLength: 80,
        barThickness: 100,
        backgroundColor: [
          '#322c83',
          '#ea7123'
        ],
        datalabels: {
          color: '#000',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
          },
          formatter: (value, context) => {
            return '$ ' + parseInt(value).toLocaleString('en-US');
          },
          //Aqui controlo la ubicacion de mis labels encima del grafico
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          offset: 0,
          display: true
        }

      }]
    },
    options: {
      // ACA agregamos padding
      layout: {
        padding: {
          top: 32
        }
      },
      //quisiera que la legenda estuviera oculta pero que tambien mi grafico se mostrara como quiero
      legend: {
        display: false,
        labels: {
          color: '#fff'
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem) {
            return tooltipItem.yLabel;
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display: false,
            beginAtZero: true,
          }
        }],

        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            display: false
          }
        }]
      }
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- for canvas chart -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
      <span style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"> Mi grafica</span>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px;margin-top:10%"></canvas>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container" style="text-align:center"></div>
</div>
```

---

**PD**: En [esta demo](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/advanced/custom-labels.html) del `cartjs-plugin-datalabels` se puede ver que también lo resuelven de esta forma.